# Why use infimum in definition of Quantile function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

This question was already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408880) (I don't know if I should just bump that question instead of creating my own or how should I do it. If I did something wrong, I'm sorry.).

The Quantile function is defined as follows:

$$Q(p)=\inf\{x\in \mathbb{R}:p\leq F(x)\}, \hspace{.1cm} 0<p<1$$

But I don't really see an example of a distribution function for which $\inf$ can't be replaced with $\min$, because CDF is necessarily a right continuous function.

And I don't think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1142474) answer is correct, because CDF is always defined on $\mathbb{R}$, it shouldn't matter what values the random variable obtains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because $F$ is right-continuous and nondecreasing, the superlevel sets of $F$ are of the form $[a,\infty)$ where $a>-\infty$ or else the entire line. When the superlevel set is the whole line, there is no min (among the reals), while the inf is $-\infty$. For $a=+\infty$ the superlevel set is empty and so the inf is $+\infty$. These cases can potentially arise when $p=0$ or $p=1$ respectively; for $p \in (0,1)$ one can indeed replace the $\inf$ with $\min$.

Comment: If we define $A(r) :=\{x\lvert Pr(X\leq x) \geq r\}$ does that then mean that for $r \in (0,1)$ open interval the inf could be changed to min?

Comment: @JesperHybel Sure. I added a sentence clarifying this matter.

Comment: thx for the quick reply. That is helpful.